# Flutter: Modelo com sublista do mesmo modelo, (Arvore de categorias)

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou a criar uma aplicação no qual faço uma chamada para uma API externa que me devolve uma lista de categorias, cada categoria pode ter uma lista de categorias (subcategorias). Não sei como posso fazer para o meu modelo ficar correto.

Neste momento tenho seguinte Model:

```
  class Category {
  String id;
  String name;
  String description;
  String slug;
  String image;
  int parent;
  int count;
  List<Category> childs;

  Category(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.description,
      this.slug,
      this.image,
      this.parent,
      this.count,
      this.childs});

  factory Category.fromJson(jsonData) {
    return Category(
      id: jsonData['id'].toString(),
      name: jsonData['name'],
      description: jsonData['description'],
      slug: jsonData['slug'],
      image: jsonData['image'],
      parent: jsonData['parent'],
      count: jsonData['count'],
      childs: jsonData['childs'],
    );
  }

  toJson() {
    return jsonEncode({
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'description': description,
      'slug': slug,
      'image': image,
      'parent': parent,
      'count': count,
    });
  }
```

e faço a requisição GET no meu category_repository que é chamado na minha store (Mobx).

STORE:

```
@action
  Future<void> getCategoriesTree() async {
    setLoading(true);
    clear();
    final response = await repository.getCategoriesTree();
    response.map((category) {
      addToCategoriesTree(Category.fromJson(category));
    }).toList();
    categoriesTree = categoriesTree;
    setLoading(false);
  }
```

Repository:

```
try {
      final response = await _woocommerce.get("get-tree-categories");          
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print('CATCH DO GETCATEGORIES - CATEGORIES REPOSITORY');
      print(e.toString());
      print(e.response.request.baseUrl);
      print(e.response.request.path);
      print(e.response.headers);
      print(e.response.statusCode);
      print(e.response.data);
    }
```

Na store faço o mapeamento do retorno e as categorias são adicionadas na lista observável "categoriesTree", mas as subcategorias que é retornado em cada categoria não ficam como um objecto Category, como faço que a "sub lista" fique também cada uma como Objecto Category?

O mesmo acontece para cada subcategoria que pode ter uma lista de subcategorias. são 3 níveis de categorias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa tratar essas sub-categorias igual fez com as categorias.

Vou lhe deixar um exemplo e você aplica para o seu caso, vamos supor que a API lhe retorna uma lista de usuários e cada usuários pode ter N emails.

> JSON retornado pela API:
>
> ```
>       {
>          "id":"001",
>          "nome":"Matheus Ribeiro",
>          "telefone":"5514981234567",
>          "emails":[
>             {
>                "email":"contato@matheus.com",
>                "tipo":"contato"
>             },
>             {
>                "email":"financeiro@matheus.com",
>                "tipo":"financeiro"
>             }
>          ]
>       },
> ```

Então vamos lá...

> Cria uma classe para guardar os dados de cada email:

```
class Email {
  Email({this.email, this.tipo});

  final String email;
  final String tipo;
}
```

> Cria uma classe para guardar os dados de cada usuário, junto a seus N emails

```
class Usuario {
  Usuario({this.id, this.nome, this.telefone, this.emails});
 
  final String id;
  final String nome;
  final String telefone;
  final List<Email> emails;
  
  factory Usuario.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Usuario(
    id: json["id"],
    nome: json["nome"],
    telefone: json["telefone"],
    emails: (json["emails"] as List).map((conteudo) => Email.fromJson(conteudo)).toList());
}
```

É neste ponto que ocorre a "mágica"

```
emails: (json["emails"] as List).map((conteudo) => Email.fromJson(conteudo)).toList());
```

No meu JSON retornado, entende que os emails vem em uma lista, então pego o valor do objeto como `List` e faço um *map* para correr cada item e ir adicionando na lista de dentro da classe `Usuario`.

Você pode ver o artigo completo que fiz aqui nesse link: [Decomplicando JSON em Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/descomplicando-o-json-em-flutter-47e12b87753b)

Comment: Era isso mesmo :) obrigado pela disponibilidade